# Cairo: How to draw a bitmap clamped to edge?

Tags: cairo

I am setting a source surface and drawing. I am getting a border of the target surface's color at the edges, if the bitmap is stretched.
I believe this is because it is interpolating at the edge with alpha=0. How can I change this so it clamps the interpolation to the colors at the edge of the source texture? This would be equivalent to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE in OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. CAIRO_EXTEND_PAD is what I needed.